# Javascript and Html - Return url adress in html code

Tags: javascript, html, url, get

I'm trying to get the full url adress of the curent page using html and javascript. But I'm don't really good at web languages so I call for you're help.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
Your website url is: <script>(window.location.host)</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5U366/92/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you could do it (not recommended is)

```
Your website url is: <script>document.write(window.location.host)</script>
```

better way would be to put a placeholder there and replace the content with innerHTML/textContent.

```
Your website url is: <span id="loc"></span>
<script>document.getElementById("loc").textContent = window.location.host;</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir! It works and it is all what I wanted.

Edit. Haha. Thank you again for such a fast respone and for solving my problem!